# Input string was not in a correct format. inventory Unity error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game in Unity and I've run into a problem. I made an inventory according to the video tutorial, I did it like in the video and something doesn’t work for me, when I click on an item in the inventory I get an error:

`` FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) (at <3ead76266f1846f192cd3a42f27e86c3>:0) System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at <3ead76266f1846f192cd3a42f27e86c3>:0) System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at <3ead76266f1846f192cd3a42f27e86c3>:0) ``

and she points to this line of code: currentID = int.Parse(es.currentSelectedGameObject.name);

The essence of the error is that I can take an item in the inventory and transfer it to another cell, and because of the error, I just click on the item and it is not taken or moved

Here is the video tutorial itself with timecode for currentID: https://youtu.be/HTlhJhRAIaU?t=242

Here is the inventory code:

```
    public void SelectObject()
    {
        if (currentID == -1)
        {
            currentID = int.Parse(es.currentSelectedGameObject.name);
            currentItem = CopyInventoryItem(items[currentID]);
            movingObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            movingObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = data.items[currentItem.id].image;

            AddItem(currentID, data.items[0], 0);
        }
        else
        {
            AddInventoryItem(currentID, items[int.Parse(es.currentSelectedGameObject.name)]);
            
            AddInventoryItem(int.Parse(es.currentSelectedGameObject.name), currentItem);
            currentID = -1;
            
            movingObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the post to keep just necessary code and add data that causes the error (inline in the code as constant value). Also for future posts avoid adding IDE tags (like "rider", "vscode", "visual-studio", "android-studio" for code *written* with these tools vs. asking about the tools themselves).

Comment: Perhaps showing us the value of said string?

Comment: Given that the code says `currentID = int.Parse(es.currentSelectedGameObject.name)`, I'm guessing that the name is not an integer. 1) see if you are parsing the wrong string. 2) always assume user input is wrong, testing it with code like `int.TryParse`. 3) you should be able to figure this out wit the debugger

Comment: You will probably need to refactor AddInventoryItem() to accept an object name as a string instead of an int.

Comment: In general .. do not use names! Rather attach a dedicated component that can provide a proper `int` value ... or even use an `enum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood my problem, it turned out that I did not correctly write off the code that was in the video. Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 1):

You try to parse a string to an int. "123" can be parsed, while "oneTwoThree" cannot. Since you copied it from the tutorial, the only difference can be the actual name of your objects. Maybe Name them "1" "2" etc.